# Window phone 8 app running out of memory

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have read a lot of different posts related to this issue. But not able solve my problem.

I seems the pages that should get disposed are not releasing their memory and all user controlls and the UI items in that are not getting deleted. 
I tried unsubscribing all the event handlers and used weak reference as well. But nothing seems to work.

I am using caliburn micro MVVM framework.

Work flow:

1 Login

2 New reservation screen

A PivotView with 8 pivot

On 8th pivot I call a service

3 Confirm Screen

A panorama with 4 pans

From first pan user can select to modify reservation.

4 Modify Screen (New reservation)

8th pivot is different this time, which contains submit button.

After submission goto confirmation screen.

5 Confirm Screen

On back press, I call `GoHome`

6 New reservation screen

I information in first 7 pivots and on 8th when I submit my app crashes.

When I tried profiling this application, I that there a lot of UI elements like Grid with destry time infinity are not getting deleted.

Go home function

```
 public void GoHome()
        {
            _dataProvider.PauseService(cancelTokenSource);
            if (_applicationState.OldReservation != null)
            {
                _applicationState.OldReservation = null;
            }

            if (_applicationState.AppToken != null && _applicationState.AppToken.TokenState == Constants.TOKENSTATUS_ANONYMOUS)
            {
                _applicationState.AppToken.Profile = null;
                _applicationState.CurrentReservation = new Reservation();
            }
            else
            {
            }
            GC.Collect();
            while (_navigationService.BackStack != null
                   && _navigationService.BackStack.Count() > 0
                   && _navigationService.BackStack.Any((entry) => entry.Source.ToString().EndsWith("/MainPageView.xaml"))
                   && !_navigationService.BackStack.First().Source.ToString().EndsWith("/MainPageView.xaml"))
            {
                _navigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
            }
            if (_navigationService.BackStack.First().Source.ToString().EndsWith("/MainPageView.xaml"))
            {
                _navigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
            }
            _navigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/MainPage/MainPageView.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
```

Comment: Any details or sample of code would greatly help. How many pages do you have? What operations do you perform that leaks crash your app? what is the behaviour you're seeing?

Comment: @zaitsman I have tried to add more details in the question. Do let me know if more required. I have been trying to solve this for a week now. Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: what message do you get when app crashes? Does the behaviour change if you remove the GC.Collect() call?

Comment: I tried putting GC.Collect() in between but nothing changed. Most of the time when app crashes I don't get any message even debugger doesn't stop. And sometimes it shows system.outOfMemory exception.

Comment: @zaitsman any idea what must be happening?

Comment: functionally speaking you are exceeding the design guidelines for the Pivot Control http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh202919(v=vs.105).aspx, suggested max is 4 pivot items. I am betting it has nothing to do with CM

Comment: @vipulmittal have you tried removing GC.Collect COMPLETELY? you are dereferencing a lot of objects in that method, and then collecting, chances are something somewhere is still referencing it.

Comment: I just put GC.Collect() after i was getting the problem. After step 6 it goes to the confirmation screen and it crashes while trying to bind the data to the UI, I guess. Because there is big increase in memory usage at that point.